# Why is Sort range not working?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a column `inProduction` that contains one of the following text values: `TRUE, FALSE, Z N/A`.

When I sort my range I expect the following order:

```
# Ascending   # Descending

inProduction  inProduction
    FALSE         Z N/A
    TRUE          TRUE
    Z N/A         FALSE
```

However, when I sort my data range using `Data > Sort range > Advanced range sorting options`, in descending order by `inProduction` with "Data has header row" selected, `Z N/A` is  incorrectly sorted to the bottom instead of the top.

I've confirmed that the `inProduction` column is formatted as text.

How can I get the correct sort?

[Link to example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/168bq72DGKNxNLXt-Jzbh95iQ2Gu93IzmPp38SB0od5E/edit?usp=sharing)

Example Incorrect Result:

```
inProduction   velocity(%)
TRUE           0.027192
TRUE           0.026422
FALSE          0.001519
FALSE          0.000254
FALSE          0.001207
Z N/A          18.17028428
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Did [doubleunary's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/166980/) solve your problem? If it did consider accepting. If not, provide additional context so they can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not text but Boolean values. The sort order used by **Data > Sort sheet** and **Data > Sort range** puts Booleans after text strings, when when you sort descending, they go to top.

You can verify whether those values are text or Boolean with the `=istext()` and `islogical()` functions.

To make it work, *first* format the column as **Format > Number > Plain text**, *then* enter the values as `true` and `false` or `TRUE` and `FALSE`. Alternatively, use formulas like `="true"`.

Comment: HI @doubleunary, you can enter the examples spreadsheet above. The TRUE FALSE cells are all set to text

Comment: There are no TRUE or FALSE values in the sample spreadsheet, and it is view-only. Choose **View > Freeze > 1 row** to make it sort correctly.

Comment: @doubleunary I can't reproduce the original issue. Sorting the data without freezing any rows works as expected. Desc: Z first. Asc: Z last. Did you confirm OP's issue in 2022? Do you think there was a bug or something changed?

Comment: Freezing rows makes a difference when using **Data > Sort sheet**, which is almost always preferable over **Data > Sort range**, including this OP's setup. I don't think there was an issue with either of those commands.